# What are the risks in using Rational Team Concert?

Tags: version-control

What are the risks invovled with using [Rational Team Concert](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/rtc/) in software development?

Comment: What is `the RTC` you speak of?

Comment: You may wish to clarify what you mean by RTC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTC

Comment: Rail Traffic Control? :P

Comment: You mean a real time clock?

LOL @ greg! Nice list ;)

Comment: I think the Rotterdam Terror Corp might be a bit more risky though..?

Comment: I meant Rational Team Concert. sorry

Comment: I'm a part of the development team that developed the RTC Client for Visual Studio, and I'm disappointed to learn that your experience with the RTC VS Client has not been satisfactory. I went back and looked at the defects the you've logged on jazz.net - we seem to have resolved most of them and those that remain do not talk about the reliability of the Pending Changes view, or menu items that are disabled inexplicably. We haven't had similar complaints from other users so I'd request you to log defects against the issues that you've described in this post, with trace files. I believe in some

Comment: Hahaha. I work for IBM and I love Git.

Answer (score 19):

I know this is sort of an old thread, but if others came by here I'dd share my personal experience.

We have been using it over the past years here and as a headliner RTC has grown into a SCM I simply don't trust with my files.

The workflows are so different that others SCM's so and as a whole the it's an over-complex and complicated system that from time to time causes you to lose your changes.

The fact that there is an article over a supposed feature called the "Backup Shed" only tells the story that I am not wrong, the fact that there is the need of such a feature tells a story in it self about how changes can suddenly disappear.
 - https://jazz.net/library/article/191/?errno=1

From other SCM's we are pretty much accustomed to that only "reverting" overwrites local changes. In RTC this happens on so many other occasions. One got to ask, how hard can it possibly be to merge files and/or conflict them in these situations?...

RTC Will overwrite files when you:

- Resync your workspace, and since you can't check in from an out of sync WS, you can't avoid this, so by god, take a backup before doing so!
- Accepting Changes, yup that's right, despite what all other SCM's does... It will offer you to check in local changes before you accept changes however, so remember to click yes to that at **PRAY** that it had discovered all local changes.
- Random?... I am fairly sure have experienced other occations where changes vanished, but only the 2 above have been things I have been able to put a finger on...
- Revert... Obviously, the only one bullet that should actually be on this list.

This may be by "design"... But then I would like to vote one for really bad design.

Also as otherwise mentioned, if you are on Visual Studio, ALWAYS click refresh remote and local changes before checking in. A solution as subversion (as old as it is) are miles better at discover changes than RTC, and so is GIT...

Besides, both SVN and Git have great implementations in many IDE's as well... I think it took a while until Git became tolerable to use within Visual Studio, but now it certainly is! Although there is still features to wish for. SVN can be integrated with many work-item/issue tracking systems as well but for the Jira integration, I actually just prefer to write the Issue numbers in the comments, it's faster and easier... And it creates the link as FishEye picks up the change sets, so Jira will display commits on issues.

I can't say how Git/Stash combo or SVN vs. YouTrack/Mingle works here. But in RTC the workflow of attaching work-items to commits becomes this huge overhead so we stopped using it = Worthless feature.

Then there is the whole planning, work-item, scrum etc. part of the system... The only part I will ever love about that is the laughs it gives me from time to time. Beyond that it's close to useless... Go Jira+GreenHopper, Mingle, YouTrack instead...

One of the funny things is that IBM tries to sell this on "Integration" and how much you save on that... Since these solutions are so wide spread there are a ton of good solutions out there where you literally can set it up and won't have to touch a finger until you decide that it might be time to upgrade to a newer version of that software. Besides all that "supposed time savings on the administrators" just go in ten-folds for them to run around and help sort out many of the issues RTC seem to have brought.

So I would advice against RTC. And Github, Codeplex, Bitbucket etc. has more than proven that things as Git, SVN etc. does in fact scale...

Comment: Just a little update on my, now close to 5 year, road with RTC... this is now coming to an end, at least there is strong motions for moving to GIT (finally)... I think Stash is the backbone of chose for hosting git, but I don't know what the final decision will be, regardless the road with RTC has been to painful and to expensive and someone finally realized that.

Answer (score 6):

We use RTC at the office and it works reasonably well. Although two things you need to know:

- It is not really a distributed versioning system like Git or Mercurial. It works more like CVS. It does support change sets though.
- Do not use it with the derby database. It crashed numerous times in our situation. We are running it on DB/2 now and now it runs stable.
- It also has support for the complete applciation life cycle but for me that is more a burden of a bloated system than a great thing to have.
- It's a great system if you come from CVS or Subversion.
- It's nothing special if you come from Git or Mercurial.

Answer (score 4):

Rational Team Concert?  Risks are, Vendor lock in, not suitable for your purpose, doesn't match your work flows,  lack of understanding or training

Real Time Clock?  lack of accuracy for your application

Real Time Control? Guaranteeing latency.  Especially on OS's that don't provide anything specific for it.   Also, RTC apps tend to be highly threaded and require programmers who take a very strategic approach to managing concurrency to achieve real time control

Answer (score 4):

I'm part of a small team that's been using the Rational Team Concert (RTC; first version 2, and now version 3) Visual Studio 2010 client every day for about 9 months now.

I agree w/ Benjamin's comments about vendor lock-in.  The "lack of understanding or training" risk has manifested itself many times for us.

**I strongly recommend against RTC's use for source control within Visual Studio**, and any Visual Studio user with freedom to choose their source control tool should be able to find a suitable alternative without too much effort. The work item tracking/etc (non-source-control featureset) is nice, but here are some thoughts about its source control integration w/ VS2010.

We've learned that RTC's "Pending Changes" pane is not trustworthy on its surface -- we must constantly (and manually) "refresh" the pane to learn what differences there *truly* are between our workstations and the repository.  It's not uncommon that we share our work with the team, only to learn that some of the files were *not* sent to the repository (resulting in a broken build for the teammates), despite the 'Pending Changes' pane telling us that no changes were pending after we "delivered" (RTC's term for a "check-in") to the team.

To make matters worse, this "Pending Changes" confusion has caused our team, multiple times, to lose code entirely.  To whatever degree our ignorance or oversight caused these losses, we've not experienced them with alternative source control products.  It regards the RTC client *thinking* we don't have any "Pending Changes" when we're accepting others' work (accepting another developer's change to a file that you've modified can overwrite your changes if RTC doesn't realize you've changed the file).

The client's "Show History" and "Compare with Previous from Repository" offerings intermittently disable themselves in our context menus.  In these moments, the manual workarounds required to see (or annotate) a file's revision history are laborious at best.

If we have too many files modified on our workstation at any given time, the "Pending Changes" pane stops showing us a list of the files -- it instead shows a count.  The number of concurrently modified files required to make this happen is in the hundreds (that's a large number, admittedly), and so it's fairly rare that we see this, but it's not unheard of for large refactorings in large codebases to impact this many files.

These are defects around only one pane.  Other behaviors around the source-control offerings of the client are buggy/unintuitive, as well.

Generally, the RTC2 VS2010 client (most of my use time) offered a quality level I associate with a beta product.  RTC3's VS2010 client (from which I made all of the above observations) is better, and brings new features (e.g. the ability to set a Current Work Item), but I wouldn't recommend it to any Visual Studio user with options who is choosing a source control product.  It remains more buggy and consistently suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Team Concert vendor lock in? Doubtful. You can always export your entire SCM repository to Subversion out of the box. All the work items can be exported via CSV files...
Or you could use the provided Java SDK to export everything... I think they made it as least lock-in as possible.

Comment: Can you point to some documentation on how to export the entire SCM history to Subversion?

Answer (score 2):

The reporting is weak.  The data that you need is there but getting it out and into a format that a customer will accept is hard to do.  I need a ProPath compliant requirements traceability matrix and its close cousin, a Verification Cross-reference Matrix (VCRM).  Good luck with that.

It is not open source.  You don't have a community of users looking over the source to identify and fix vulnerabilities.  This latter is why the Pentagon (US military) is becoming more accepting of open source; it is hard to slip a Trojan horse into code that everyone is looking at.

What is not a risk is that you will eventually be able to get your job done.  No one ever got fired for picking IBM.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

To respond to the original question, my team and I have been using the VS Client for RTC since our first milestone about 3 and a half years ago and we have a large user base now,so I'd recommend posting this question on https://jazz.net/forums/viewforum.php?f=17.

To answer your questions:

1. There are no vendor lock-ins. I'd say we have a really open story compared to a lot of the other tools in the change and configuration management domain.
2. RTC has a good integration story with Visual Studio. It's totally native, built around VS packages, and integrates well with VS's solution explorer, properties, tools, error view, editor framework and so on, giving a native look and feel for VS users.
3. There are a bunch of blogs, articles, videos and forum posts on jazz.net - you could have a look at those to get a feel for the integration.
4. You can also create a sandbox on jazz.net and connect to it using the RTC VS Client to figure out the experience for yourself.

Cheers

--Rupa

Comment: A lot of other source controls support fast export streams. RTC does not. On that alone, I'd say vendor lock in is pretty high on the list.

Answer (score 0):

The risks in **not** using Rational Team Concert are

1. Using tools that don't integrate well with each other. RTC has integrated planning, bug tracking, source control, build and reports. So you can easily see what fixes went into a particular build, what code was changed and why. You can comment on the work item when you don't like the fix in the code, take a screenshot to illustrate a point.
2. Using tools that don't grow with your project. You can get started quickly with RTC using a predefined process template. As you add more members, more teams, more code, you can tweak the process rules to decide who should verify the bugs, tighten the rules toward the end of a release, automate builds, setup staged streams. etc. RTC is used by small teams and huge teams.
3. Using tools that only work for developers or managers but not both. With RTC, managers get to build fancy dashboards to track the health of the project in the Web UI. Developers can work within their IDE on Windows, Linux, Mac (Eclipse, VS on Windows). There's also a command line tool. And more is coming, their 4.0 Beta features a new Windows Explorer client. Because an IDE is cool for a developer, but not so cool for a tester or a graphic designer.
4. Using tools that lock you into a particular OS. As said in 3. maybe today your project is mostly Windows, but what about tomorrow? RTC has clients for Windows, Linux and Mac.

But just like I go to the Apple store to try the latest gadget, you can go to [www.jazz.net](http://www.jazz.net) and download a trial of RTC to see by yourself. Import a bit of your data into it and see how it feels for you and your team.